# Quadratic formula is not working half the time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I have made a quadratic formula in python, it looks like this:

```
import math
a, b, c = input("Enter a, b and c: ").split()
a, b, c = int(a), int(b), int(c)
print((0-b + ((b**2) - (4*a*c))**0.5)/2*a)
print((0-b - ((b**2) - (4*a*c))**0.5)/2*a)
```

On some questions it works, but when you input "5 9 1" it does not give the correct answer.

Comment: what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: @tuqay to solve a question using the quadratic formula, inputting 5 9 1 should output -1.6810249675907
-0.11897503240933

Answer (score 4):

You have to put `2*a` into parentheses in the formula:

```
(...)/(2*a)
```

In an expression like

```
(...)/2*a
```

you first divide by 2 and then multiply by `a`.

Comment: It's called [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).